# square for loop pattern

Tags: java, for-loop

I am facing a problem that my brains cant handle!
I need to make loop that creates pattern like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

so the inner the number is the bigger its but I just can't figure how could i create such loop
I need this for my AI so i can create interest areas for entities, so this is no school assigment and what i have tried so far

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
      System.out.print("?");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

I really cant think of a way to get the number that represent which level is it on!
I've been trying to visualize this to myself etc. to figure out how would be the best way to create this or create this at all.. Please help me and my brains from getting headache! :) what i want is simple pseudo code or code in any language that is easy to understand (such as java, c++, c...)

Comment: i==0  is the first row.   j==0 is the first column

Comment: you'll have less of a headache if you just try to learn about the for loop without that square for a moment. Just print i and j, and print *, and try to figure out how the for loops work together. if you don't even know how to get the number that represents which level you're on, then work on that would be less of a headache and would prepare you better for the square. it's less steep. That much is obvious, you have to be able to break things down as a programmer.

Comment: I knew how loops worked together but I didn't got the idea how could i possibly calculate the "level" (distance to border) of the current number as I never thought i could calculate the distance to the closest border (thanks sth) but thanks anyway

Comment: This was really a mathematical puzzle then, given i and j, you can calculate any number in the grid, what's the mathematical formula. That was your real problem. There is a maths stackexchange site you could've asked that in, and there wasn't any need for any programming help, if your problem was finding a formula.. especially if you -knew- there was a formula. You weren't asking how to calculate what level you were on at all. You were asking what mathematical formula would calculate the number for any point on the grid, given the x,y position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
      // The distance to the left, right, top and bottom border:
      int dl = j;
      int dr = cols - (j+1);
      int dt = i;
      int db = rows - (i+1);

      // The distance to the closest border:
      int d = Math.min(Math.min(dl, dr), Math.min(dt, db));

      // Print according number
      System.out.print(d+1);
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: *rubs eyes* that's just perfect! Never thought of calculating distance to closest border! Thanks seriously, you made my day!

Comment: @Ruuhkis - you should probably "accept" this answer if it's the best one to help you with your problem :) You can do that by clicking the "tick" to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The number you want is the minimum distance to the edge either horizontally or vertically. In pseudo code:

```
min(i, j , n - 1 - j, n - 1 - i) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your "?" be 1+ the min of i, j, (rows-1)-i, and (cols-1)-j.

Answer (score 0):

So the distance from the outside in one dimension is this (let's consider rows first):

```
distanceR = min(i, rows - 1 - i)
```

Where `min` is some function that returns the smaller of two values.

OK, let's do the same thing again for the columns:

```
distanceC = min(j, cols - 1 - j)
```

Now the value you want to compute at each cell is:

```
min(distanceR, distanceC) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int dim = 5;
    int level = 1;
    String line;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        int l = 0;
        line = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {

            if (j < (dim / 2)+1) {
                l++;
                if (l > level) {
                    System.out.print(level);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(l);
                }
            } else {
                l--;
                if (l >= level) {
                    System.out.print(level);

                } else {
                    System.out.print(l);

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

        if (i<dim/2)
            level++; 
        else level--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //create pyramid

        int intCounterX = 0;
        int intCounterY = 0;
        int intElevationX = 0;
        int intElevationY = 0;
        int intElevation = 1;
        int intSide = 5;
        int intMid = (intSide + 1) / 2;

        for (intCounterY = 0; intCounterY < intSide; intCounterY++)
        {
            for (intCounterX = 0; intCounterX < intSide; intCounterX++)
            {
                //determine if we're on an edge
                if (intCounterX == 0 || intCounterY == 0 || intCounterX == (intSide - 1) || intCounterY == (intSide - 1))
                {
                    //edges are always 1
                    intElevation = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //increasing elevation to mid, decreasing after
                    //for X
                    if (intCounterX < (intMid - 1))
                    {
                        //going up
                        intElevationX = intCounterX + 1;
                    }
                    else if (intCounterX == (intMid - 1))
                    {
                        //point
                        intElevationX = intMid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //must be going down
                        intElevationX = intCounterX - 1;
                    }

                    //for Y
                    if (intCounterY < (intMid - 1))
                    {
                        //going up
                        intElevationY = intCounterY + 1;
                    }
                    else if (intCounterY == (intMid - 1))
                    {
                        //point
                        intElevationY = intMid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //must be going down
                        intElevationY = intCounterY - 1;
                    }

                    //take the lower of the two
                    if (intElevationX < intElevationY)
                    {
                        //X is lower
                        intElevation = intElevationX;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Y is lower or equal
                        intElevation = intElevationY;
                    }
                }

                Console.Write(intElevation);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, which indexes the first element at 1 it's:

```
n = 5;
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        a = [i, j , n - j + 1, n - i + 1];
        fprintf('%d ',(min(a)));
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows:int=7;
var cols:int=7;

var mid:int=Math.floor(rows / 2); //Gives the 0 based index of middle row
var max:int=mid+1;
for(var i:int=0; i<rows; i++) {
    var s:String="";
    var diff:int=mid - i;
    var maxNum:int=max - Math.abs(mid - i);
    //trace(maxNum);
    for(var j:int=0; j<cols; j++) {
        var dta:int=Math.abs(j - mid)
        if(max - dta > maxNum) {
            s += maxNum;
        } else {
            s += (max - dta);
        }
    }

    trace(s);
}
```

Here's my code in ActionScript (a java environ not being very handy on my comp). If you'll wait a few minutes, I'll post the java code also

**EDIT**

```
int  rows=7;
int  cols=7;

int  mid=(int) Math.Floor((double)(rows / 2)); //Gives the 0 based index of middle row
int  max=mid+1;
for(int  i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    int  diff=mid - i;
    int  maxNum=max - Math.Abs(mid - i);
    //trace(maxNum);
    for(int  j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        int dta=Math.Abs(j - mid);
        if(max - dta > maxNum) {
            System.out.write(maxNum);
        } else {
            System.out.write(max - dta);
        }
    }

    System.out.writeLine();
}
```

**output**

```
1111111   
1222221   
1233321   
1234321   
1233321   
1222221   
1111111
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch, because i'm a nutter

```
C:\>t
11111
12221
12321
12221
11111

C:\>
```

You can change from   m=5 n=5  to  m=7 n=7  e.t.c.

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


set m=5
set n=5
set /A m_minus1=m-1
set /A n_minus1=n-1

SET /A amid=(%m%+1)/2
SET /A bmid=(%n%+1)/2

for /L %%a in (1,1,%m%) do (
  for /L %%b in (1,1,%n%) do (
    IF %%a==1 SET STRING=!STRING!1
    IF %%a==%m% SET STRING=!STRING!1
     IF %%a GEQ 2 (
         IF %%a LEQ %m_minus1% (
              IF %%a==%amid% (
                 if %%b==%bmid% (
                       SET STRING=!STRING!3
                  ) ELSE (

                   IF %%b==1  SET STRING=!STRING!1
                   IF %%b==%n%  SET STRING=!STRING!1
                   IF %%b GEQ 2 (
                      IF %%b LEQ %n_minus1% (
                         SET STRING=!STRING!2
                      ) %/IF LEQ %
                   ) % /IF GEQ %

                  ) % /ELSE %




              ) ELSE (   % /IF a mids equal/not equal % 


                   IF %%b==1  SET STRING=!STRING!1
                   IF %%b==%n%  SET STRING=!STRING!1
                   IF %%b GEQ 2 (
                      IF %%b LEQ %n_minus1% (
                         SET STRING=!STRING!2
                      ) %/IF LEQ %
                   ) % /IF GEQ %

              ) % /ELSE of IF a mids equal/not equal % 

        ) % LEQ 4 %        
    ) % GEQ 2 %
  ) % b for %

  ECHO/!STRING!
  SET STRING=
) % a for % 

endlocal
```